# Ruby on Rails link_to directing to Index instead of Show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

I am having trouble with some Ruby on Rails code. I have a data structure of nested resources (List has_many Tasks and a Task belongs_to a List). On my List.show page, I have the following line of code:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show Task', list_tasks_path(@list, task) %></td>
```

The idea is that this page will link to a "show" page where I can view the details of an individual Task. I want the url to basically be

```
/lists/:list_id/tasks/:task_id
```

The problem is that the above code is directing me to

```
/lists/:list_id/tasks.task_id
```

on the index page of Task. How can I tell Rails to send me to the show page instead?

I have tried adding :action => show and :controller => tasks, as well as using show_list_tasks_path(@list, task). I also know that the structure itself is there because my show page works fine if I manually enter /lists/:list_id/tasks/:task_id.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

-Sum

Comment: what do your routes look like? what does 'list_task_path' do (instead of 'list_tasks_path')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're using `list_tasks_path` when you should be using `list_task_path`.

The `list_tasks_path` method will generate a URL to the `index` action, as you know already, and will make the second argument be the format for this request.

For more information please read the [Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help! Also, thanks for the reference web site.

Comment: The output of `rake routes` is extremely useful.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way to specify this url would be

```
<%= link_to 'Show Task', [@list, task] %>
```

You can also do `list_task_path(@list, task)` (notice *task* instead of *tasks*).

Run `rake routes` to see exact names rails generates for your routes.